# font configuration warning

Tags: 12.04, server, compiling, gcc, c

when I was doing c program in Ubuntu 12.04 , there is a font configuration warning shown by terminal. What should I do?

```
shayna@shayna-Vostro-3446:~$ gedit hello6.c
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-loma-synthetic.conf", line 12: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 26: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 31: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 40: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
shayna@shayna-Vostro-3446:~$ gcc hello6.c -o hello6
shayna@shayna-Vostro-3446:~$ ./hello6
shayna@shayna-Vostro-3446:~$
```

Comment: everything is working properly but please tell me the way by which i remove these warnings and do my c program properly without any warnings..

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing, such warnings are common when you run a GUI app from the terminal. Is anything not working properly?